# QGIS 3.44 heatmap to contour file

Tags: qgis-3, heat-map, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert a point file, currently displayed into a contour file. The methods that I have tried, all expect a raster file as an input, but my source file is a vector file points, i.e. [image: Input displayed as heatmap]

I have tried the gdal colour plugin with the following results [image]

Not what I was expecting, I was hoping for a blob that represented the deep red in the first image and perhaps some other bands. There must be a better way of doing this unless I have missed something important! Any sugggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the **Contour plugin** which takes point vector files as input?

Comment: Is the first figure you displayed above rendered by the QGIS heatmap renderer? Or did you compute a density raster using a processing algorithm?

Comment: The  1st drawing is the result of displaying point data as a heatmap as per the drop down menu on on the 'Symbology' tab of the properties.

If helps each point has a 'value' field  associated with it.

I begining to wonder if there is better way of generating a heapmap